# Should I pinch early pear blossoms to encourage stronger tree and better season?

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-health, pruning, pear

I have a young pear tree that has several varieties of pears grafted on it. It is starting to blossom. Should I pinch these early blossoms? Will the tree divert resources to making more leaves and produce a second wave of blossoms? How many of these blossoms should I pinch?

Answer (score 4):

How young? I would remove all fruit if the tree is in its first or second year, because it forces the tree to use all of its energy getting established instead of producing fruit.

edit: if you have a multi-way tree, often you will find that one or two of the grafts grow *much* faster than some of the others. you should prune the fast growing grafts aggressively so as to promote the slower growing grafts.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: it forces the tree to use all of its energy getting established instead of producing fruit.